# handlebars view not refreshing when {{#if}} {{else}} condition changes

Tags: ember.js

(edit: simplified things a bit below)

I have a handlebars template with an {{#if etc}} conditional, and when I change the associated data the view updates the first time, but then does not continue to update on subsequent changes. I am toggling a boolean that is in the condition, and I know the toggle is running and switching the property because I can watch it do so on the console, but the actual view, a I said, only refreshes once. In my html file this looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
<body>
<div class="row">
  {{#if App.Nav.show}}
     {{outlet nav}}
  {{/if}}
  <div class="span10">
     <h1>Hello</h1>
     {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</script>
```

and a bit further on, to toggle:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">                                                                                                                                                
   <a {{action toggleMenu}}> toggle </a>
</script>
```

and in the javascript:

```
App.NavController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.NavView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'nav'
});
App.Nav = Ember.Object.create({
    show: true
});
```

and finally the relevant bits of the router:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
        showPerson: Ember.Route.transitionTo('aName'),
        toggleMenu: function(){
           console.log('Changing the toggle!');
           App.Nav.toggleShow();
        },
        connectOutlets: function(router){
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('nav', 'nav');
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('allPeople', unrelated_function())
        }
    })
   })
});
```

Comment: It's clear in retrospect that the view is actually updating and that my problem is that the outlet is getting disconnected and is not automatically reconnecting... if I make the function take the router as an arg and connect it if needed, it works. Is this the best practice?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? you just want to hide/show a view or anything else?

Comment: In this case, yes - is there a more canonical way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use `connectOutlet` to display the view, let me know if there is some purpose behind using `connectOutlet` method, Meanwhile [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yStCs/4/) is my implementation of toggling the view visibility

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. You're correct - I don't need to use an outlet for the navigation bar, I can just use a view. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would say to put your if into your view. Something like this:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">
      <a {{action toggleMenu}}> toggle </a>
      {{#if App.Nav.show}}
            <div>navigation</div>
      {{/if}}
      <div class="span10">
           <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      </div>
 </script>
```

Then your application view should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
     <body>
          <div class="row">{{outlet}}</div>
     </body>
</script>
```

Let me know if you tried it and it worked.

Comment: Thanks - this works as well. I'd like to be able to keep possible optional "view" elements at a higher level in the view stack, but this does succeed in predictably hiding the nav bar.

Comment: The higher level might be much heavier on your DOM. It could be a good idea to stick to smaller changes.